# sed : how to print all lines after line with a match?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I got my research result after using `sed` :

```
zcat file* | sed -e 's/.*text=\(.*\)status=[^/]*/\1/' | cut -f 1 - | grep "pattern"
```

But it only shows the part that I cut. How can I print all lines after a match ?

I'm using zcat so I cannot use awk.

Thanks.

**Edited :**

This is my log file :

```
[01/09/2015 00:00:47]       INFO=54646486432154646 from=steve   idfrom=55516654455457       to=jone       idto=5552045646464 guid=100021623456461451463   n
um=6    text=hi my number is 0 811 22 1/12   status=new      survstatus=new
```

My aim is to find all users that spam my site with their telephone numbers (using `grep "pattern"`) then print all the lines to get all the information about each spam. The problem is there may be matches in INFO or id, so I use `sed` to get the text first.

Comment: Can you show sample output of `zcat` with your expected output?

Comment: "I'm using zcat so I cannot use awk." Wait, what?

Comment: It's still not clear what output exactly you are trying to obtain.

Comment: How about you told us more precisely what your log file is (like, if it's only the single line you pasted, you don't need sed, you don't have to give it all but give us more), and what you actually expect to come out. With words *and* with an example. Nobody can read your mind.

Comment: I think JB means that the output of `zcat` is just standard text, so you could pipe it to `awk` no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is what you actually want?  Find lines matching "pattern" and extract the field after `text=` up through just before `status=`?

```
zcat file* | sed -e '/pattern/s/.*text=\(.*\)status=[^/]*/\1/'
```

You are not revealing what `pattern` actually is -- if it's a variable, you cannot use single quotes around it.

Notice that `\(.*\)status=[^/]*` would match up through `survstatus=new` in your example.  That is probably not what you want?  There doesn't seem to be a `status=` followed by a slash anywhere -- you really should explain in more detail what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Your question title says "all line after a match" so perhaps you want everything after `text=`?  Then that's simply

```
sed 's/.*text=//'
```

i.e. replace up through `text=` with nothing, and keep the rest.  (I trust you can figure out how to change the surrounding script into `zcat file* | sed '/pattern/s/.*text=//'` ... oops, maybe my trust failed.)

Comment: Actually you probably want `... | sed -n '/.../s/.../.../p'` to print only the extracted lines.  This is easy to do with Awk as well; not sure why you think you can't use Awk for this.

Answer (score 94):

To print all lines after, and including, the first match:

```
$ echo -ne 'apple\nbanana\ncherry\n' | sed -ne '/banana/,$ p'
banana
cherry
```

To print all lines after, and NOT including, the first match:

```
$ echo -ne 'apple\nbanana\ncherry\n' | sed -e '1,/banana/ d'
cherry
```

Filtering lines when pattern matches between "text=" and "status=" can be done with a simple `grep`, no need for `sed` and `cut`:

```
$ grep 'text=.*pattern.* status='
```

Comment: This works. Don't forget the `-n` else it *will* print everything regardless.

Comment: What is the -e flag doing here?

Comment: @Caterina: it makes explicit the fact the next argument is the script itself.

Comment: @Caterina It's unnecessary.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `awk`

```bash
awk '/pattern/,EOF'
```

n.b. don't be fooled: EOF is just an uninitialized variable, and by default 0 (false). So that condition cannot be satisfied until the end of file.

Perhaps this could be combined with all the previous answers using awk as well.

Comment: this is perfect for me, I didn't know about using EOF in awk until now!

Comment: don't let that trick you, EOF is just a uninitialized variable, and by default 0 (false). So that condition cannot be satisfied until the end of file.

Comment: I've edited that in, hope that's ok

Answer (score 3):

The seldom used branch command will do this for you. Until you match, use n for next then branch to beginning. After match, use n to skip the matching line, then a loop copying the remaining lines.

```
cat file \
| sed -n -e ':start; /pattern/b match;n; b start; :match n; :copy; p; n ; b copy'
```

Comment: For the record, [the `cat` is useless.](/q/11710552)

Comment: For the record: 'cat is useless' coments are ill-thought through.  He, or I, may have been doing something like 'zcat FILE.gz | <intricate sed command> just two command-lines before the current line, and 'gunzip FILE.gz' one command-line before the current. With history and readline, he, and I, can now hit the up-arrow twice, hit the home arrow, delete one character (the 'z'), and hit ENTER to run the command you abhor. Ergo: 'cat is useless' comments are often less keen than they are clueless.

Answer (score 0):

```
zcat file* | sed -e 's/.*text=\(.*\)status=[^/]*/\1/' | ***cut -f 1 - | grep "pattern"***
```

instead change the last 2 segments of your pipeline so that:

```
zcat file* | sed -e 's/.*text=\(.*\)status=[^/]*/\1/' | **awk '$1 ~ "pattern" {print $0}'**
```

Answer (score 0):

By simply using : grep -A$numberoflines "Word" file
If you dont know the numberoflines use wc -l

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?