# sed line range not respected if match on first line

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I am trying to parse a file that looks as follows:

```
$ echo -e "[Header]\nbar\nfoo\n[more]\na\nb"
[Header]
bar
foo
[body]
a
b
```

Suppose I want everything after the `[body]` line.  I can do this:

```
$ sed  -e  '1,/^\[body\]/d'   
a
b
```

But that analogous command does not work if I want everything after the `[Header]` line:

```
$ sed  -e  '1,/^\[Header\]/d'
```

produces nothing.

Why doesn't `sed` seem to respect the line range, which is effectively `1,1` in the second command?

While there are certainly alternative approaches to get the desired result (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569032/sed-print-all-lines-after-match), suggested in a comment below by @Wiktor Stribiżew), this question is about why the above command does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed : print all lines after match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569032/sed-print-all-lines-after-match), see https://ideone.com/db2tRZ

Comment: no, not a duplicate. I am aware of alternative ways to accomplish the same thing. The question was why the apparently properly formulated command did not give the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual page of [Gnu sed](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/sed.1.html#addresses):

> Sed commands can be given with no addresses, in which case the command  will  be  executed for all input lines; with one address, in which case the command will only be executed for input lines which match that address; or with two addresses, in which  case  the  command will  be  executed  for  all input lines which match the inclusive range of lines starting from the first address and continuing to the second address.
>
> Three things to  note  about address  ranges: the syntax is *addr1*,*addr2* (i.e., the addresses are separated by a comma); the line which *addr1* matched will always be accepted, even if  *addr2*  selects  an earlier line; **and if *addr2* is a regexp, it will not be tested against the line that *addr1* matched.**

Comment: Correct. You can use `0,/^\[Header\]/d` to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The info `sed` states:

> If the second address is a REGEXP, then checking for the ending
>   match will start with the line *following* the line which matched the
>   first address: a range will always span at least two lines (except of
>   course if the input stream ends).

While it is possible to argue for other interpretations (which will allow for single line match), this decision was made long time ago, and is hard to change because of compatibility issue.